# Is there any way to show the last times Android was rebooted?

Tags: reboot, logging

Is there any way to show the last times Android was rebooted?

I'm using `uptime -s` for the last time, but I would like to see a list of the last times it was rebooted.

I'm on Android 9 and Termux.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need to specifically use Termux? Also, probably related: [Does Android keep a log of when it boots?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26080/44325)